# Calculating total cost per month sql

Tags: sql-server

I want to work out the total cost for a specific month, my code is generating the items purchased that month but it is calculating the cost of all the items instead of just that month

```
set dateformat 'dmy' 
Select OrderID, OrderDate, UnitPrice
From SupplierOrder
Where OrderDate between '01/07/2015' AND '31/07/2015' 
group by OrderID, OrderDate, UnitPrice
SELECT SUM(UnitPrice) AS TotalCostOfItems FROM SupplierOrder;
```

Comment: Sum on unitprice sounds odd. Are you sure there is no quantity or amount field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little confused as to why you have two queries. Regardless, the first is filtering on date, but the second is not - hence the second query is calculating the summed unit price for *all* orders. To get the second query working, simply add the same filter that you have for the first

```
SELECT SUM(UnitPrice) AS TotalCostOfItems FROM SupplierOrder Where OrderDate between '01/07/2015' AND '31/07/2015';
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add the where statement after your select.

```
SELECT SUM(UnitPrice) AS TotalCostOfItems FROM SupplierOrder
Where OrderDate between '01/07/2015' AND '31/07/2015'
```

hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select mnth, yr, sum(unitprice) unitprice
from
(
SELECT 
DATEPART(month,orderdate) mnth,
datepart(year,orderdate) yr, 
unitprice
from supplierorder
) a
group by mnth, yr
```